# What does the html attribute "opts" mean?

Tags: html

I found the following code snippet on a ajax-website:

```
<a href="#" class="nav" opts="page:about;fadein:0;fadeout:0"> About </a>
```

I've never seen the attribute `opts` before. It's hard to find something in google.
For what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means nothing. It is non-standard and invalid. Presumably it is being used by JavaScript in the page.

The standard way to store data for JavaScript would be with [`data-` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes)

Comment: It is non-standard and invalid if they aren't calling a custom DTD which we have no way of telling from the information provided. However, if they set a custom DTD on this page, it could be used to do just about anything they wanted.

Comment: @Tabetha Moe: A custom DTD is non-standard as far as HTML is concerned.

Comment: @BoltClock: No argument there. But it does exist and people do use them. This could be the case. Not saying it is, but saying that it is a possibility. There are all kinds of sites on the web that break standards. This could be one of them. Until OP posts the document type declaration, we have no way of telling.

Answer (score -1):

I did a little research on Google and it appears they are using a Custom Document Type Declaration or Custom DTD.

http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/customdtd.html

Comment: Care to share this research?

Comment: I'd be astonished if as many as 0.1% of sites using expando-attributes wrote a DTD to support them.

Comment: Yeah, it is rare. Perhaps the OP could share the head information and we can see what is going on.

Comment: Whether they are using a custom DTD or not is immaterial. It would only matter to them if they used a validator.

Comment: Just found this... using custom attributes for jQuery. http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-creating-custom-attributes-in-html     Seeing how I've never done anything like this, I didn't know what they were doing. Don't understand why I'm getting down voted if my answer was actually one of many possibilities with what limited information we had.